# How to remove prefixes in strings on Windows command line?

Tags: string, batch-file

Suppose I wanted to echo every executable inside the %programfiles% folder

```
cd %programfiles%
for /r . %i in (*.exe) do echo "%~i"
```

but it yields

```
c:\program files\program1\program1.exe
c:\program files\program2\program2.exe
```

and I want

```
program1\program1.exe
program2\program2.exe
```

How to remove those prefixes?

Comment: What is the prefix for you? Only the first level? What do you want for `C:\progam files\program3\Application\bin\program3.exe`?

Comment: @jeb I want `program3\Application\bin\program3.exe` because the prefix is `c:\program files\`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the string replace function of batch

```
pushd %programfiles%
set "prefix=%programfiles%"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /r . %i in (*.exe) do (
  set "progPath=%~i"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "progPath=!progPath:%prefix%=!"
  echo !progPath!
  endlocal
)
popd
```

Answer (score 5):

Put this in a batch file and run, it should do the job.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd %programfiles%
for /r . %%i in (*.exe) do (
    set pth=%%~fi
    set val=!pth:%cd%\=!
    echo !val!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [jebs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335341/8262102)

This one is if your batch file is not on the same drive as that you're working on so a different approach needs to be taken.

The code has comments included.

```
@echo off
::
rem Based of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335341/8262102
title Removes prefix from directories example...
set "dirBase=C:\Program Files\Common Files"
cd /d %dirBase% &rem changes to the directory.
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /r . %%A in (*.exe) do (
  set "progPath=%%~A"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "progPath=!progPath:%dirBase%=!"
  echo .!progPath!
  endlocal
)
echo/ & pause & cls
```

Comment: instead, you could use `CD /D C:\Program Files\Common Files`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Amended the post.

Comment: But now you don't need `set dirBase=...`, `set dirDrive=...` nor `%dirDrive%` anymore

Comment: Thanks again. I've had to leave the `set dirBase` in there as this was an example of the batch file being run from a different drive.