# Getting path from string in batch

Tags: batch-file

I wish to get a parse a string in batch in the following way:

Let's say I have this path as a string in batch:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Test

I wish to remove a give string from this string. For example, if I call it with:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft

I'll get:

> Test

If I call it with:

> C:\Program Files

I'll get:

> Microsoft\Test

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove prefixes in strings on Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335007/how-to-remove-prefixes-in-strings-on-windows-command-line)

Comment: The post didn't much help. I wish to get the string which needs to be cut as a variable, and stay with the rest..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
set p=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Test
echo %p:C:\Program Files\Microsoft\=%
echo %p:C:\Program Files\=%
```

Comment: almost...I think I know why it doesn't work. I'm sending a full path of a file to a function, and in the function I'm extracting the full path (without the filename) ---> using `%~dp2`. Then, I'm extracting the absolute path into a variable using a for loop. So, now I have these variables: `!CurrentDir!` and `!Prefix!` which are `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Test` and `C:\Program Files` respectively. I tried to edit your second line into this: `%CurrentDir:!Prefix!=%` - but that doesn't work...

Comment: Ah right, without seeing the rest of the batch I can't really say why it doesn't work, but if you are using `!CurrentDir!` then `%CurrentDir%` probably won't work the same way. To nest delayedexpansions you could use `call` or a `for`, but it depends on why it isn't working, it's just an idea.